# How do I cast type aclitem to text or varchar in psql?

Tags: text, casting, enumeration, varchar, psql

I am attempting to do a like/~ operation with an aclitem and am having problems.  I cannot cast this type to a text or varchar type, so I am unable to use the like or ~ operators.  I am having the same trouble with the cstring type.  My guess is that this is somehow enumerated, but I can't seem to find the key.  Any ideas?

This is the type of query I'd like to run:

```
select
   case when relacl[1] ~ '%searchstring%' then 1 else 0 end as temp1,
   case when relacl[1] like '%searchstring%' then 1 else 0 end as temp2,
   case when aclitemout(relacl[1]) ~ '%searchstring%' then 1 else 0 end as temp3,
   case when aclitemout(relacl[1]) like '%searchstring%' then 1 else 0 end as temp4,
   relacl[1]::text as temp5,
   relacl[1]::varchar as temp6,
   aclitemout(relacl[1])::text as temp7,
   aclitemout(relacl[1])::varchar as temp8
from
   pg_class c
;
```

Answer (score 2):

relacl is an array type, so you can use array_to_string(array(relacl)) to convert it to a searchable string.